# Tracing the packets through wireshark

Tags: networking, wireshark, packets, network-security

I am trying to capture the packets moving from my system when i searched URL ***www.google.com*** in the browser. This is the flow I am seeing in **wireshark**.

1. DNS request was made
2. TCP three-way handshake is done
3. TLSV1.2 handshake has started.

In between **tlv1.2 handshake** I am seeing TCP packets moving from my system to the same port. What is that traffic regarding? I am sharing the screenshot for the same.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The TCP packets with description "ACK" are TCP acknowledgement packets.
An acknowledgement packet is sent to the server for each time the client receives a TCP data packet from the server.

The TCP packets with description "TCP segment of a reassembled PDU" are TCP fragmented data packet.
TCP may divide an upper layer packet into multiple packets. A TCP fragmented data packet is a piece of a divided packet.
For example, the TLS server certificate packet (#1842) was divided into 3 packets by TCP, #1839, #1841, and #1842.